# Изменение значения в атрибуте в рантайме

Tags: c#, атрибуты

пускай у меня есть некий атрибут в который я кидаю данные, и который я цепляю на класс:

```
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string name = "";
    public AtrAttribute(string q) => name = q;
}

[My("ARTUR")]
class myclass{ }
```

возможн ли поменять то значение атрибута ("ARTUR" на "DMITRY") уже в рантайме, если да, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак.

> It's important to note that these Attribute objects are instantiated
>   lazily. That is, they won't be instantiated until you use
>   GetCustomAttribute or GetCustomAttributes. They are also instantiated
>   each time. Calling GetCustomAttributes twice in a row will return two
>   different instances of ObsoleteAttribute.
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes

Из примера выше:

```
var instance0 = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(myclass)).
      OfType<MyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
var instance1 = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(myclass)).
      OfType<MyAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
var equals = Object.ReferenceEquals(instance0, instance1); // always false
```